# access IObservable inside same IObservable subscription

Tags: c#, iterator, system.reactive

Here is a bare-bones example of what I'm trying to do with Reactive Extensions, but it does not work

### Add does not work in this simple example

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        var obs = list.ToObservable();
        IDisposable subscription = obs.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(p =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(Add(obs).ToString());
        },
        err => Console.WriteLine("Error"),
        () => Console.WriteLine("Sequence Completed")
        );
        Console.ReadLine();
        subscription.Dispose();
    }

    private static int Add(IObservable<int> wholeList)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        wholeList.ForEach(i => sum = sum + i);
        return sum;
    }
```

### Actual Output

```
1
_
```

### Desired Output

```
1
6
2
6
3
6
Sequence Completed
_
```

i.e. i would like to **execute a method Add(obs) inside each iteration, where obs is itself the cold IObservable undergoing the iteration?**

Comment: You're most likely Doing It Wrong(tm) here. Can you describe your scenario and what you're trying to accomplish at a higher level?

Comment: @Paul please see the comment i just added to Enigmativity ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As par your comment I would suggest that you make the observable to generate the items as required and not do this stuff after subscription. In you example you can do something like:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var obs = list.ToObservable().Select(i => new Tuple<int,IObservable<int>>(i,list.ToObservable()));

obs.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(t => {
  Console.WriteLine(t.Item1);
  SaveItems(t.Item2);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
IDisposable subscription = obs.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread)
```

to this:

```
IDisposable subscription = obs.ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread)
```

You should note that you're doing a bad thing as far as Rx is concerned. You are moving in and out of the observables. You should avoid this where ever possible.

So, for example, avoid this:

```
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var obs = list.ToObservable();
```

when this is the same:

```
    var obs = Observable.Range(1, 3);
```

Also the whole `static int Add(IObservable<int> wholeList)` method is bad. It calls `ForEach` (which generally should be a warning that you're doing something wrong) to take the values out of an observable. This is where dead-locking can occur.

There already is an observable extension called `Sum` which returns an `IObservble<int>` and this doesn't take you out of the observable.

So try writing your code like this:

```
var obs = Observable.Range(1, 3);

var query =
    from n in obs
    from s in obs.Sum()
    select new
    {
        Number = n.ToString(),
        Sum = s.ToString(),
    };

using (var subscription = query.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(
    x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Number);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Sum);
        },
    err =>
        Console.WriteLine("Error"),
    () =>
        Console.WriteLine("Sequence Completed")))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, and i take your points! Unfortunately, I need to use .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread) for reasons not illustrated here, is there another way to do MyMethod(obs) at the end of each iteration?

Comment: @Cel - I changed my example code to use `SubscribeOn` rather than `ObserveOn` and it still works. This is an example of where staying in the observables works when going outside of them dead-locks so you should avoid calling your `MyMethod(obs)`.

Comment: i think i should have posted the intended MyMethod(obs) in the first place, because Add(obs) does not really model the scenario well. The desired MyMethod is actually SaveMessages(obs), so what i would like to do is not to Sum integers, but at the end of each individual message iteration, i would like to save ALL the messages contained within obs. and i dont want to save all the elements in obs at OnCompleted only, i need to do that at the end of each iteration?

Comment: @Cel - Then change the signature to `static IObservable<int> Add(IObservable<int> wholeList)` and then use standard operators or `Observable.Create<T>(...)` inside the method.